# Removed digits while inserting into mysql (php)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hi
I´m inserting data (just 3 fields) in a mysql table.

The problem is when inserting one of those, a number (3 digits) in a tinyint (also tried TEXT, VARCHAR and other fieldtype), the result is only the first digit is added.

The other fields, numbers also, are inserted with no problem.

I'm using a function that calls this simple code:

```
$idT= $_POST["idT"];

function related( $idE, $idT, $Type  )
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name ( idE, idT, Type ) VALUES ( '$idE', '$idT', '$Type ')";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

return mysql_insert_id($conn);
}
```

The problem is with `$idT` variable.

Comment: It would be helpful to execute the command `DESCRIBE table_tame` and post the Field and Type columns as well.

Comment: And better escape $idT before you go inserting it. Let someone submit `0'); DROP TABLE table_name;` and it will ruin your day.

Comment: If you need a humorous break, you might appreciate this [xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/327/) is applicable to SQL injection. (I know it's been excessively linked before!)

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be the values you are trying to insert are beyond the storage capacity of the [MySql numeric type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) `[TINYINT]` (which ranges from -127 to 127 signed, or 0 to 255 signed).

You may need to change the table structure such that the column(s) which are `TINYINT` are `INT(#)` instead.

Comment: The number after `INT` is the bytes allocated for storage. With just 2 bytes allocated, you can store ints from 0 to 65535 (unsigned). Be careful that you didn't use INT(1) because that has the same storage as the default `TINYINT`.

Comment: @nikkas `TINYINT(3)` will still limit you to 1 byte storage. I ran this command: `UPDATE table SET tiny = 858 WHERE id = 1;` and the result was 255. Check the numeric type documentation for more info. (`SMALLINT` caps at 2 bytes, `INT` caps at 4, etc.) Also, per Knowledge Craving's answers and comments, ensure that the value you are passing to SQL is the correct value. You can also bypass PHP and experiment with communicating more directly to MySQL via command line or use a utility such as [SQLyog Community](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/).

Comment: @JYelton, problem is not in the table; I tried inputing a number instead of the variable, in the SQL code, and it works. Something is truncating the variable in there..

Comment: @nikkas: What does your $sql string look like just before you run `mysql_query`? Insert `echo $sql;` just before the line beginning with `$result =`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are changing only the "**Data Type**" field (whether it be "`VARCHAR`", or "`INT`", or "`TINYINT`"). You need to change the field "**Length/Values**" also to "`3`" ("`TINYINT UNSIGNED`"), or "`4`" ("`TINYINT SIGNED`"), or "`4`" ("`INT SIGNED`").

Hope it helps.

---

The simplest way to trace any code in PHP is by echoing the required / interested variable(s) (if it is string / integer) or by using "`var_dump` / `print_r`" for all other variables, just after each assignment statement & after each function calling.

Comment: Hi, I just did that ("3" ("TINYINT UNSIGNED") but the same, only the first digit is added.

Comment: @nikkas - Have you tried printing the Insert SQL code, just before firing it in some PHP function to be executed?

Comment: Yes. When I print the SQL code that number is appearing already cutted off. But when I print the var, it´s OK...

Comment: I see now where exactly the variable is being cutted. I have the code inside a function:


function related('$idE', '$idT', '$Type ')

If I print it BEFORE this, the number is fine.
If I print it AFTER, it´s printing only 1 digit.

Any idea?

Comment: @nikkas - As per your last comment, you must have the following code:-
`echo $idT.'--'; $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name ( idE, idT, Type ) VALUES ( '$idE', '$idT', '$Type ')"; echo $sql;`  
Now you should see whether the two values are equal or not. Because I feel that some (manipulation) work is being done on the variable "`$idT`", before it's put in the "`$sql`" variable.

Comment: @nikkas - Try tracing the function definition "`function related()`" for each line, since you will know better where any manipulation is being done on the *local function* argument "`$idT`".

Comment: I´m afraid I´m too new in PHP and don´t know how to trace it... :(

Comment: Hi, I´m doing that. It appears that right before the INSERT call everything is just fine. After it, it echoes the wrong number. The SQL code is a single line and doesn´t seem to be changing any format...

Comment: Yes, I get a different value before: 2-- instead of 28--, number is being manipulated before... but how!? :D

Comment: @nikkas - Please provide the code snippet in the question, so that other SO users can pinpoint the error(s).

Comment: @ Knowledge Craving - no clue ?

Comment: @nikkas - no clue, if possible, please post the code for the full page, along with the code for the form page. There must be some other place from where all these is getting wrong.